# Generating a single output file for each processed input file in Apach Flink

Tags: scala, etl, apache-flink

I am using Scala and Apache Flink to build an ETL that reads all the files under a directory in my local file system periodically and write the result of processing each file in a single output file under another directory.

So an example of this is would be:

```
/dir/to/input/files/file1
/dir/to/intput/files/fil2
/dir/to/input/files/file3
```

and the output of the ETL would be exactly:

```
/dir/to/output/files/file1
/dir/to/output/files/file2
/dir/to/output/files/file3
```

I have tried various approaches including reducing the parallel processing to one when writing to the dataSink but I still can't achieve the required result.

This is my current code:

```
   val path = "/path/to/input/files/"
   val format = new TextInputFormat(new Path(path))
   val socketStream = env.readFile(format, path, FileProcessingMode.PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY, 10)


   val wordsStream = socketStream.flatMap(value => value.split(",")).map(value => WordWithCount(value,1))

   val keyValuePair = wordsStream.keyBy(_.word)

   val countPair = keyValuePair.sum("count")

   countPair.print()

   countPair.writeAsText("/path/to/output/directory/"+
     DateTime.now().getHourOfDay.toString
     +
     DateTime.now().getMinuteOfHour.toString
     +
     DateTime.now().getSecondOfMinute.toString
     , FileSystem.WriteMode.NO_OVERWRITE)

// The first write method I trid:

   val sink = new BucketingSink[WordWithCount]("/path/to/output/directory/")
   sink.setBucketer(new DateTimeBucketer[WordWithCount]("yyyy-MM-dd--HHmm"))

// The second write method I trid:

   val sink3 = new BucketingSink[WordWithCount]("/path/to/output/directory/")
   sink3.setUseTruncate(false)
   sink3.setBucketer(new DateTimeBucketer("yyyy-MM-dd--HHmm"))
   sink3.setWriter(new StringWriter[WordWithCount])
   sink3.setBatchSize(3)
   sink3.setPendingPrefix("file-")
   sink3.setPendingSuffix(".txt")
```

Both writing methods fail in producing the wanted result.

Can some with experience with Apache Flink guide me to the write approach please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue importing the next dependencies to run on local machine:

- hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar
- aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.183.jar
- aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.183.jar
- aws-java-sdk-kms-1.11.183.jar
- jackson-annotations-2.6.7.jar
- jackson-core-2.6.7.jar
- jackson-databind-2.6.7.jar
- joda-time-2.8.1.jar
- httpcore-4.4.4.jar
- httpclient-4.5.3.jar

---

You can review it on :

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/deployment/aws.html

Section "Provide S3 FileSystem Dependency"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you clarify how this answers the,question, please?

Comment: I have added the jars and created the BucketingSink to write the output files. now I can run it on my local machine and obtain the desired output file structure. Thanks a lot for the help Fransico.

Comment: Hi Mandy! Because the code is correct, and the execution was failed by the dependencies, If you can see the documentation, Flink comment that if you execute with YARN, these dependencies are implicits by the hadoop framework, but if you want execute on the local machine, you should import them.